# Have background image extend leftward from div

Tags: html, css

A simple illustration of my problem:

[image: illustration of my problem]

I am trying to build the a page with a specific width, but I want a header image to extend 50px to the left of the rest of the website.

Bear with me a bit.

The code snippet below shows my current html and css:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
</body>

body: {
  background-color: #FDFBDC;
}
#header {
  background: transparent url('images/headerforweb.png') no-repeat -50px 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is for the image to extend 50px left of the #header div. However, I want #header to be centered, so I have to set margins left and right to auto. Also, I cannot know the distance marked with "?", as it will depend on the client's screen size.

The problem is that, with my approach, with the image set as a background to #header, the extra 50px are being clipped. I looked around and found that a background image cannot extend beyond its element's size.

I have also tried enclosing #header in a wrapper div, which extends to the full width of the page, and set the image as background to that. However, in that case, I need to know "?", to set it as a left margin to the image background, but it's impossible to know.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by making the image a child of the header, and then using a negative margin left.

Like this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DRdhX/)

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="image">
  </div>
</div>​

#header { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    background: red;
    height: 80px;
}

#image {
    margin-left: -50px;
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
}​
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid this solution, as I had other contents to the header and I thought the image would mess them up, but I tried it and it did work. And then I saw your solution, so I guess you get the tick :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include another span with in header and pass the background-image to that span. add position:relative to #header. and position:absolute;left:-50px;top:0 to the newly created span.

Comment: Thanks, I think this answer would work too, I just used the other one and it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Or just use position:relative on an enclosing div which carries your image.

```
body: {background-color: #FDFBDC;}
#header {
color:#ccc;
width:800px;
height:600px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

div.header_image { position:relative; left:-50px; top:0px;      background:url(images/headerforweb.png) 0 0  no-repeat;}



<div id="header">
<div class="header_image"> 
<h1>CONTENT</h1>
<h2>MORE CONTENT</h2>
<h3>MORE CONTENT</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jonrp, you better provide your answer with working JSFiddle example! It would be easier to qualify!